# Is this possible to customize auth.log about which key was used?

Tags: ssh

I use a classical pair of private/public key in order to connect into servers.

For now, we have one dedicated account, let's say `foo`, which is used by multiple users, each with their own pairs of public/private keys.

I am looking for a way to log which user authenticated on this `foo` account.

For now, I manage to found that if I raise `LogLevel` to `VERBOSE` in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, ssh log the *fingerprint* of the public key in **/var/log/auth.log**.

It looks like this :

```
Apr  2 18:33:15 xxx-yy sshd[32064]: Connection from A.B.C.D port 43286
Apr  2 18:33:15 xxx-yy sshd[32064]: Found matching RSA key: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Apr  2 18:33:15 xxx-yy sshd[32064]: Accepted publickey for foo from A.B.C.D port 43286 ssh2
```

I then manage to get *fingerprint* of each users with a call to `ssh-keygen -lf key.pub` on their public key and then apply a sed on the log.

I would like to know if there's a simpler or a better way to have ssh log which user's key was used to authenticate on the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshd never sees which key filename is used by the client, so postprocessing cannot be avoided.

Comment: I guess I'll have to manage ssh auth. via ldap and/or local account, then.